# Skip URL Routing for specific path in Angular 8 and Apache

Tags: angular, .htaccess, apache2

I have an 2 Angular Application : FrontEnd and Admin. Both of these are hosted on cpanel behind apache server. The setup of website is like below.

mydomain.com/ ----> Frontend Angular Application

mydomain.com/admin ----> Admin Angular Application

Now when i open mydomain.com/admin then it is properly redirected to Admin Angular Application, the problem occurs on refresh. On refreshing it loads FrontEnd Angular Application and tries to find path for '/admin' in FrontEnd Angular Application.

Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteRule api/(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [L,P]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

FrondtEnd Angular Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: UserDashboardComponent,canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
];
```

I tried googling but all efforts were futile. And pointers in this direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why you need two angular applications in the first place ? build the admin part like other components and add guards to protect the admin routes depending upon the user

Comment: It is required to have two different Angular Application for FrontEnd and Admin, this problem woudn't have come if it was a single Application.

Comment: why not have another name as                                           
mydomain.com/user ----> Frontend Angular Application

mydomain.com/admin ----> Admin Angular Application                                                     and edit this accordingly <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteRule api/(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [L,P]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule> which is pretty much redirected to  /